# Kendo Grid - Prevent multiple calls to database after Custom filter binding

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We are using some background filtering to bring data in kendo grid.
We are showing filtered data based upon some columns
So we have requirement to show that filters in kendo grid.
After databound we are applying these filters to grid to show filtered columns

Here is the code snippet.

```
                var rows=grid.DataSource;
                var filterArray;
                 filterArray[0]={field: 'Duration',
                                 operator: 'Equal',
                                 value: 20
                                }
                 filterArray[1]={field: 'AgentName',
                                 operator: 'Contains',
                                 value: 'a'
                                 }

                 rows.Filter(filterArray);
```

but when apply filters  Kendo make servre call to get data again based on filters, which  we don't want because we have alredy displayed filtered data.

Is there any way to show filter column on grid without making server call ?We just need to set filter values in the filter textboxes.

Comment: Can you post your grid declaration?

Comment: Does dataSource.serverFiltering = true?

Comment: Yes datasource.Serverfiltering is set to true.But that our implementation.We have enabled server side filtering.My implementation is like the following way.I have one dropdown on change of which i am filtering data from server side and filters are already saved in database against id of selected item from dropdown.Now we need to show that filter values in the grid filters which we are applying it from server side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be achieved by these steps:

1. Setting the filter
2. Refreshing the grid (not the datasource)

Example code:

```
var filterArray = new Array();
filterArray.push({field: 'Duration', operator: 'Equal', value:20});
filterArray.push({field: 'AgentName', operator: 'Contains', value: 'a'});
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._filter = { logic: "and", filters: filterArray };
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```

Live example can be found [here](http://kendogridbinderex.apphb.com/Employee) (*Fill in something at FirstName contains and click the Add Filter button*)

Comment: Hi Stef.I implemented just few days ago and its working fine for me.Thanks for your reply